# Which shell am I using in vs code terminal?

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code

I used `Remote - SSH` extension to connect to Linux host via VS code. In the terminal, I selected zsh as you can see from below screenshot

[image]

But when I execute

```
echo $SHELL
```

It outputs: **/bin/bash**.

[image]

But it seems indeed I am using zsh:

[image]

I think even though $SHELL shows it is bash. But when it comes to execution, it is zsh. Have I messed up something here since they are not consistent?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [echo $SHELL shows `/bin/bash` as the output even after changing the default shell to zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/558373/echo-shell-shows-bin-bash-as-the-output-even-after-changing-the-default-shel)

Comment: Yeah, it kind of does. Then how would I know which shell I am using if SHELL is set by the login program. Specifically when I am indeed using zsh while SHELL is /bin/bash. There might be a command other than echo $SHELL.

Comment: it depends on how the shell is started. using something like `-E` will preserve the home's etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```sh
ps -p $$
```

This will pass in current process ID (i.e. your shell) and return the name.